# Dúvida em JavaScript + SQLite3, retorno do Select

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sqlite3, electron

Olá, preciso recuperar informação de um banco e exibir em uma tabela.
Estou utilizando electron e sqlite3.
Tenho essa  função para fazer a consulta.

```js
function getTable(){
  var obj = [];
  var aux = [];
  db.each('SELECT nome, categoria, grau FROM receita', function(err, row) {
    aux.push(row.nome);
    aux.push(row.categoria);
    aux.push(row.grau);
    obj.push(aux);
    aux = [];
  });
  return(obj);
}
```

Após eu fazer a consulta quero que me retorne o array de elementos, porém ele retorna um array vazio, mas se uso o console.log consigo ver os elementos, só não consigo acessar eles, quando tento acessar diz que é vazio.
Estou usando jquery.DataTable e com ele vc declara o table no html e no js vc chama ele assim:

```js
var obj = getTable();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#receitaTable').DataTable( {
    data: obj,
    columns: [
      { title: "Nome" },
      { title: "Categoria" },
      { title: "Grau" }
    ]
    }); 
});
```

Porém a consulta do meu select não deixa eu "tirar os elementos pra fora", eu posso usar se estiver tudo dentro do db.each('SELECT nome, categoria, grau FROM receita', function(err, row) {....
Porém se eu uso o dataTable dentro do db.each... ele apresenta erro, pois irá criar a tabela diversas vezes.

RESUMINDO: queria saber como faço a consulta e pego o elemento salvo numa variável, que mesmo eu dando db.close, o elemento fica salvo na variável.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Só jogar os valores no array não vai ter permitir agrupar cada linha que retorna do banco, e ler com os nomes que precisa (Nome, Categoria, etc). Precisar criar um objeto e adicionar um objeto que represente um "row", assim:

```
db.each('SELECT nome, categoria, grau FROM receita', function(err, row) {
    var obj= {
       "Nome": row.nome,
       "Categoria": row.categoria,
       "Grau": row.grau
    };

    aux.push(obj);
  });
```

Assim mais claro o que tem dentro do seu objeto, um array de objetos com atributos "Nome", "Categoria" e "Grau".